# Retrieve data by foreign key

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I have two tables in my database Users and Complains.

Users table :

id | name | password

Complains table

id | user_id | title | body

The user_id is a foreign key. How do I retrieve title and body from the complains table based on the user_id?

This is what I have so far but I cannot retrieve data specific to the user_id

My User Model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'surname', 'regnumber', 'course', 'department', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

My Profile Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Complain;
use App\Feedback;
use App\Item;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Session;
use Auth;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function profile($user_id){

        $user = User::whereId($user_id)->first();

        $complains = Complain::paginate(2);

        return view('user.profile', compact('user', 'complains'));
    }

}
```

My view:

```
@foreach($complains as $complain)
   <div>
       <h3 class="operator-complain-title">Title: </h3>
       <p>{{ $complain->title }}</p>
       <h3 class="operator-complain-title">Complain:</h3>
       <p>{{ $complain->body }}</p>
   </div>
   <hr>
@endforeach
```

Anyone with any ideas please share.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to setup a one-to-many relationship as outlined here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Once you have the correct methods in place, Eloquent will find relations when you do something like `$user->complains`.

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the complains for the User.
     */
    public function complains()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Complain');
    }
}

class Complain extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the User for the Complain.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: My User model does not extend Model, it extends Authenticatable. If I add the relationship will the logic work?

Comment: Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User extends Model. It'll work for you.

Comment: I have created the relationships in my complain and user models respectively. In my controller I have : $complain = Complain::find($id);
return view('user.profile')->withComplain($complain); but on my view I get this error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: This is my view : @foreach($complain as $complains) {{ $complains->title }} @endforeach

Comment: Change: return view('user.profile')->withComplain($complain); to return view('user.profile')->with(['complains' => $complains]);

Comment: @foreach($complains as $complain) {{ $complain->title }} @endforeach. Use that in your view, you have the variables swapped. Remember, plural -> singular.

Comment: I have changed that : @foreach($complains as $complain) {{ $complain->title }} @endforeach now I see this error : Undefined variable: complains

Comment: Oh, you have $complain = Complain::find($id); that is only pulling one record. I think what you want is the User's complaints? Then it would be something like: view('user.profile')->with(['complains' => User::find($id)->complains]);

Comment: yes what I want is the user's complaints. I have changed to view('user.profile')->with(['complains' => User::find($id)->complains]); and now I see this error : Trying to get property of non-object pointing to that line of code.

Comment: Do you have a Complain model? Can you post it if so.

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Complain extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'user_id', 'title', 'body', 'name', 'regnumber'
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}

Comment: That's my complain model

Comment: What is the primary key on your user model? That is saying it's 'user_id'. Try removing the second argument all together: this->belongsTo('App\User')

Comment: public function complains()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Complain');
    }

Comment: That is the method in my user model, I have removed the second parameter and still the error persists.

Comment: Can you add your two table migrations or their structure to the original post? Have you setup foreign key relationships within the DB?

Comment: I have posted my migrations.

Answer (score 0):

This is my users table migration :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

This is my complains table migration :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateComplainsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('complains', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('complains');
    }
}
```

This is the migration I used to add foreign key to complains table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddForeignKeyToComplains extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('complains', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->after('id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('complains', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the foreign key relationship on complains to users. Make user_id unsigned and add this right below it: $foreign->('user_id')->references('id')->('users');

Comment: Should I add this : $foreign->('user_id')->references('id')->('users'); in my migration file?

Comment: yes at the line below this: $table->integer('user_id')->after('id')->nullable();

Comment: It is throwing a parse error : PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' inC:\xampp\htdocs\SCS\database\migrations\2017_06_08_175638_add_foreign_key_to_complains.php on line 18

Comment: $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

Comment: Now there is an sql integrity constraint violation error :  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`student-complain-system`.`#sql
  -109c_54`, CONSTRAINT `complains_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: alter table `complains` add constraint `comp
  lains_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

Comment: Drop your database and start fresh with a new migration if you can. You can't update existing records without giving them an id to an existing foreign entity. One work around may be to add ->default(1); or something to your user id column.

Comment: I dropped my db, made the foreign key unsigned and added this : $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); dd() still returns null..